# How to add Google drive folder & files to Google site search index

Tags: google-drive-api, google-search, google-sites

I have created a web page on my Google site that uses a Google Drive widget to display Drive files.  The Google site has the site level search enabled and I would like to be able to add the Google drive files that are embedded within the new Google site page to the Google site search so that when users of the site conduct a search they will also search against Drive files embedded within the site.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think non , you don't have a Google Drive Gadget , you can add Google doc , presentation , spreadsheet , but not a Google Drive Gadget.

Comment: Sorry not sure you read my question.  I can add a Google Drive widget, that's not the problem.  I would like to include the drive files to the google site search.

Comment: ah sorry , yes you can't , google sites search concern google sites only.  I think it's not possible.